Ubuntu/Debian Repository Architecture
I'm deploying a local repository and I would like to know more about the architecture of Ubuntu and Debian package repositories.
I know that packages are stored in http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool if I'm not wrong :

main - Officially supported software
restricted - Supported software that is not available under a completely free license
universe - Community maintained software
multiverse - Software that is not free

But where are stored the system files ? If they are in http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dist/jammy why is there main/ restricted/ multiverse/ universe/ directories like in pool/ directory and why are the files so small. Same in dist/jammy-security.
Moreover, pool/ directory is not in a dist/directory so how the operating system know if a packet is compatible or not with the os version ?
